# Summing to an int variable from values of an event subcribed to in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, websocket, event-handling

I am not sure how to calculate a summation of numbers from an event that is subscribed to in C#.

I have created an int variable Summation1 and I am able to Console.Writeline() the value of Summation1, as well as the value of temp as temp is updated by the event.

Summation1 will always stay at 0 which is the value that it was initialized to. I would like Summation1 to have a running summation of the variable temp each time temp is updated (this will be later used to calculate an average of temp). The value of temp shows properly using Console.Writeline() but I am not sure how to get Summation1 to have the sum of all of the temp values up to that point.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading;
 using tyllibrary;
 using System.IO;


 namespace SKTtest
 {
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {

             TYLSocket socket = new TYLSocket();
             socket.Connect("188.2.2.112", 2800);

             int Summation1 = 0;

             socket.eventPool.Subscribe("flight", new EventHandler<flightArgs>((x, y) => Console.WriteLine(y.STR1.temp + " " + Summation1)));
             socket.SubscribeEquip("gulfstream");
 

             Console.ReadKey();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: You couldn't come up with `Summation1++`?

Comment: That would only increment Summation1 by 1? I want a dynamic sum of temp

Comment: do `(Summation1+=y.STR1.temp)`  then ... https://ideone.com/ycQlwh

Comment: please paraphrase your question

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand exactly, but you can use the following code to calculate the average temperature. Total temperature divided by total the number of times the total temperature

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    TYLSocket socket = new TYLSocket();
    socket.Connect("188.2.2.112", 2800);

    int Summation1 = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    socket.eventPool.Subscribe("flight", new EventHandler<flightArgs>((x, y) =>  {
       counter++;
       Summation1 += y.STR1.temp;
       Console.WriteLine("average temp : " + (Summation1 / counter));
    }));
    socket.SubscribeEquip("gulfstream");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```